# Voice recording while taking note

Tags: android, note-taking, voice-recording

I am looking for a voice recorder software for Android that would allow me to take notes which would be timestamped with respect to the recording.

E.g. I start recording the voice. After 1 minute, I write a note: "Hello". Then 25 minutes later, I write another note "this is a test". The note should be timestamped like (any format is fine):

```
Note 01 (1 minute): Hello
Note 02 (26 minutes): this is a test
```

Answer (score 2):

[**Cogi-Notes and Voice Recorder**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cogi.mobile)

> Cogi is an easy-to-use, free and ad-free note taking and voice
>   recording app that allows you to capture only the important parts of
>   meetings, lectures and conversations – all while remaining completing
>   engaged, listening to what’s being said.
>
> Cogi puts you in control, letting you record only the “aha moments”
>   from your conversation that caused you to think, “Gee, I should write
>   that down”. Rather than taking notes by writing them down, count on
>   Cogi to record the important things you hear.
>
> Add images, text and tags to the voice notes to completely capture the
>   details of any meeting or lecture. Review only the important
>   highlights without listening to the entire conversation again.

It has built-in tools that helps you write notes in your lectures and capture the whiteboard with camera too.Can record while screen is turned off or using some other app too.And its absolutely free. This is how notes look like when saved:
[image]